# Twilio api asking for 'FROM' number each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twilio

using the Twilio Ruby gem and I'm passing the params for 'to' and 'body' from a form view helper within :message and I defaulted and set the 'from' number within the code, but each time I run it , I'm getting:

Twilio::REST::RequestError in MessagesController#create

A 'From' phone number is required.

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

(other methods in here as well)

def create


user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @account_sid = '******'
  @auth_token = '**********'
  from = '+1347*****'
  body = params[:message][:body]
  to = params[:message][:to]
  from = '+1347******'
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)

  # this sends the sms message 
  @client.account.sms.messages.create(body => :body, from => :from, to => :to)

  # this saves the form message in the model Message
  user.messages.create(body => :body, from => :from, to => :to)

  redirect_to '/'
end
```

Comment: If you run into any other issues where you're getting unexpected results, you can use this to inspect your API calls: https://www.runscope.com/docs/code-examples/twilio (yes shameless plug I know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your hashes all seem backwards

```
user.messages.create(body => :body, from => :from, to => :to)
```

should read

```
user.messages.create(:body => body, :from => from, :to => to)
```

in your examples you are setting a key with value of body, from, and to, to the symbols body, from, to.